# Mistake in Visited Days in Stack Overflow profile

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Just now I noticed one thing about the Visited Days in my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/pm-paresh-mayani), I don't know whether this is the actual format implemented by Stack Overflow team or whether it's an issue.

Actually I have **visited** Stack Overflow for 367 days, what do you think? Should it be **367 days or 1 year 2 days?** I think it should be same as above line of "Member for" section.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It makes sense to count the days individually, since they're discrete instances (i.e. individual visits). You didn't actually visit the site for an entire *continuous year* and two days. <sup>(Or did you? That'd mean you were staring at it 24/7 for a year...)</sup>

They're also probably that way to reflect their associated badges (Yearling: # years of membership; Enthusiast/Fanatic: # days visited).

Comment: That way Even i haven't visited the site for an entire Continuous 367 days.

Comment: You've visited it *on* 367 days.  You have visited it *on* two years, 2010 and 2011.  Saying 1 year wouldn't match either of those and the latter is so broad as to be useless.